# Magento 2 Email Template If Shipping Method Then Do Something

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, shipping-methods, email-templates

I have a custom shipping module and I am trying to execute some information in an email template based on the shipping method chosen.  I have tried things like:

```
{{if order.getShippingDescription() == 'Shipping Method - Shipping Title'}}
<p>{{trans "Works!"}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

How can I target the shipping method and show information based on that method in the email template?

UPDATE
I have tried creating a plugin in Vendor/Module/Plugin/Order/Email/Container/EmailCode.php:

```
class EmailCode
{
    public function beforeSetTemplateVars(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template $subject, array $vars)
    { 
        /** @var Order $order */
        $order = $vars['order'];
        $method = $order->getShippingMethod();

        $vars['shipping_code'] = $method === 'freedelivery_freedelivery';

        return [$vars];
    }
}
```

and I added in etc/frontend di.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template">
        <plugin name="email.shipping.code" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Order\Email\Container\Template\EmailCode" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and then this in my email template:

```
{{if shipping_code}}
<p>{{trans "Email Code Works"}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

And it didn't work.  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Stan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this by adding an observer and calling it in events.xml.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class EmailTemplateVars implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository) 
    {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }
    
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
        $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
        
        if($transport->getOrder() != null)
        {
            $transport['checkout_building_address']   = $transport->getOrder()->getCheckoutBuildingAddress(); 
            $transport['checkout_floor_number']       = $transport->getOrder()->getCheckoutFloorNumber(); 
            $transport['checkout_room_number']        = $transport->getOrder()->getCheckoutRoomNumber();  
        }
    }
}
```

etc/events.xml

```
 <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="somename_checkout_custom_fields_add_to_email" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\EmailTemplateVars"/>
    </event>
```

In the email template:

```
<p><strong>{{trans "Building Address"}}</strong><br />{{var checkout_building_address|raw}}</p>
<p><strong>{{trans "Floor Number"}}</strong><br />{{var checkout_floor_number|raw}}</p>
<p><strong>{{trans "Room Number"}}</strong><br />{{var checkout_room_number|raw}}</p>
```

Stan